# Jqgrid modal dialog customization

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to add placeholder text to my jqgrid modal dialog textbox and I have two textboxes in modal dialog.
If first textbox is empty than second textbox should be in disable mode.
If first one is not empty then second textbox will be enable.
How can achieve it using jQuery.

Comment: You should post JavaScript code which shows what you do. It's unclear currently which "modal dialog" you mean. Do you create "modal dialog" by call of `$.jgrid.createModal` or `$.jgrid.info_dialog` method you you mean some other dialog like Searching Dialog or Add/Edit dialog?

Comment: Default jqgrid add and edit dialog,
And how can I access dialog controls ids in jQuery script

Comment: To make it easy you should include the code which you use to create the grid and the code where you call `navGrid`. In general you can use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback of form editing to solve your problem. You should access the input textbox by id (which corresponds the value of `name` property of the corresponding columns of `colModel`).

Comment: Tq. Placeholder worked for me but now how can I validate two textboxes using JQuery script